# Appositive relative clause - verb omission

Tags: appositives

I am struggling with this sentence:

> Each year more than a thousand people, **half of whom children**, die
>   in bicycle accidents.

Why can the verb 'to be' be omitted in this sentence?

Comment: I don't think a native speaker would omit *are*.

Comment: It's a typo.  It should be "half of whom are children".

Comment: Or it could also be "half of them children". It's easy to get mixed up among pronouns in English.

Answer (score 2):

If you google "Participial Construction", there will be a lot of examples where *being* and *having been* are omitted. The reason is that they are *predictable*.

> Each year more than a thousand people, half of whom **are** children,
>   die in bicycle accidents.

This sentence can be rephrased to:

> Each year more than a thousand people, **and** half of **them** are
>   children, die in bicycle accidents.

and using *Participial Construction*, you can change it to:

> Each year more than a thousand people, half of them *(being)* children,
>   die in bicycle accidents.

If you want to use *half of whom* in place of *half of them*, **are** should not be moitted as *whom* is an *object pronoun* and the subject *half* needs **the verb *be***.

Answer (score 0):

It is "are" which is omitted here. **half of whom are children...**

Such sentences are called elliptical constructions and they usually omit the words which are implied but not actually present.

https://www.aje.com/en/author-resources/articles/editing-tip-elliptical-constructions